# How can I change the HDMI resolution when also using the PiTFT?

Tags: hdmi, pitft

I've got a Raspberry Pi B+ with Adafruit's PiTFT 2.8" touchscreen.

Plugged it into my TV (that supports 1080p resolution) via HDMI and used

```
FRAMEBUFFER=/dev/fb0 startx
```

And X started up on the television. But it started up in the wrong resolution - 592x448.

Firing up `arandr` that's the only resolution option it offers. How can I make it use the proper resolution (i.e. 1080p) without messing with the PiTFT?

Comment: Have you looked at http://askubuntu.com/questions/148646/force-startx-to-run-x-in-a-specific-resolution-and-refresh-rate?

Comment: @PhilB. that looks like it might point me in a direction to find an answer on my own...

Comment: If it does give you an answer on your own, just come back here and post your solution as an answer ... that way if anyone ever needs the same question answered, they know how to proceed.